# transparent triangle with border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Trying to create a transparent triangle div with a colored border.

css

```
#down {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0; right: 0;
 width: 0; height: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 z-index: 20; 
 bottom: 0; 
 border-bottom: 55px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.75); 
}
```

putting a div on-top another div ruins the transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use gradients and/or transform:

- on left: square + border-top/left + transform + gradient to draw the bottom border:
- on middle : yours
- on right : border-bottom + gradient for the triangle top borders

[both extra example can hold content](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pyQjyq) such as font icone / text / image .

```css
body {
  background:tomato;
}

#rotate {
  position:fixed;
  border:solid turquoise;
  border-bottom:none;
  border-right:none;
  bottom:7px;
  left:calc(50% - 180px);
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 3px), turquoise calc(50% - 3px), turquoise 50%, transparent 50% ); 
}

#bg-gradient {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:5px;
  left: calc(50% + 70px)  ;
  border-bottom:solid turquoise;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, turquoise 50%, turquoise calc(50% + 3px), transparent calc(50% + 3px) ),linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%, turquoise 50%, turquoise calc(50% + 3px), transparent calc(50% + 3px) ) right
    ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  height:55px;
  width:110px;
  
}

#down {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0; right: 0;
 width: 0; height: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-left: 55px solid transparent;
 border-right: 55px solid transparent;
 z-index: 20; 
 bottom: 5px; 
 border-bottom: 55px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.75); 
}
```

```html
<div id="down"></div>
<div id="rotate"></div>
<div id="bg-gradient"></div>
```

Notice that a rotated square at bottom can have half being hidden

Comment: can the bottom line of the triangle be removed and the triangle pushed to the complete bottom of the page?

Comment: @user3550879 of course, remove the gradient (#rotate) or border-bottom (#bg-gradient)  and reset the bottom value http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOQJVZ

Comment: Whilst I'm not overly keen on gradients, this is quite a nice solution. +1

Comment: @jbutler483 complexe gradients + background-size can slow down badly browsers, to test and use with care ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done with border tricks, and those are not really helpful for this

You need others techniques for that.

For instance, see this CSS

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, lightblue, yellow)
}

.trapezoid {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.trapezoid:before {
    content: '';
    width: 57%;
    height: 100%;
    left: -4%;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.trapezoid:after {
    content: '';
    width: 59%;
    height: 100%;
    right: -4%;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 3px 3px 0px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

Comment: well with some adjustments I managed to make a square with what i need, but not a triangle

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy solution, but it uses CSS `transform` which isn't supported by IE lower than 9.0.

Remember that this triangle is at the very bottom of the page, so a rotated square can be used.

```css
#down {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: -47px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.75);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: 3px solid #ffaa33;
}

#down-inner { /* Must be rotated back */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

body {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #444444;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="down">
    <div id="down-inner">A rotated square</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how bad is the support with other browsers and mobile etc.? also how cn a fallback be coded in?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this with fewer lines of code.

```css
body { 
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500390365106-166bb67248d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2434&q=80) no-repeat top; background-size: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.triangle { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30%;
  height: 158px; 
  width: 182px; 
  background: white; 
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 1.75% 100%, 50% 3%, 97.5% 98.35%, 1.75% 98.35%, 1.75% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

The hexagon version is also shown here:
https://codepen.io/smeyer/pen/gOPmxqm

You can play with the numbers to alter the border width.